# How to avoid memory leak when dealing with KMeans for example in this code, I am trying to find the best WCSS to use in KMean clustering

Tags: python, k-means

```
wcss = []

for i in range(1,10):
    kmeans = KMeans(i)
    kmeans.fit(x_scaled)
    wcss_iter = kmeans.inertia_
    wcss.append(wcss_iter)
```

I get the following warning when I run the code:
C:\Users\grahv\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster_kmeans.py:881: UserWarning: KMeans is known to have a memory leak on Windows with MKL, when there are less chunks than available threads. You can avoid it by setting the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS=1.
warnings.warn(

Answer (score 11):

As the warning says:

> UserWarning: KMeans is known to have a memory leak on **Windows** with MKL, when there are less chunks than available threads. You can avoid it by setting the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS=1.

Ignoring such a warning is not a good choice at all! So it's better to try to put effort into solving the issue. to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to `1` in Windows 10, You should follow these steps:

1. Hit <kbd>Windows Button</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. search for "**Edit the system environment variables**"
3. click on "**Environment variables...**"
4. in the System Variables section, click on "**New...**"
   [image]
5. Fill the fields with suitable content(as what mentioned in warning of sklearn):
   [image]
6. click on "**OK**" and **restart your machine**.

Then you can try to run your code without getting the warning.

Answer (score 9):

you can set the environment variable by

```py
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = '1'
```

before import kmeans

Comment: It does not work, the warning persists.

Comment: You need to do it before numpy is imported.

Comment: This might slow things down, as it limits everything to one thread. I'd rather suppress the warning (see answer from @NIK) and live with the memory leak as it is tiny.

Comment: the warning has gone, but has to use this solution at the beginning of the solution

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same warning. I didn't find anything relevant to this. So I used

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

to ignore the warnings.

Comment: But this just hides the warnings, while OP's question was how to avoid the actual memory leak.

Comment: Whatever the memory leak is, it's tiny. For short-running jobs, the script will probably end before the leak gets too bad, and the process will free the memory.